# fitting data to LSTM layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to implement a multi-label classification of numeric data using LSTM layers, with three possible labels, each data also has three features. When I give the dimensions of my `train_x` to the first LSTM layer as `input_shape` I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 30258, 3), found shape=(None, 3)
```

Data and their shapes:

```
train_x.shape = (30258, 3)
train_y.shape = (30258, 3)
test_x.shape = (7565, 3)
test_y.shape = (7565, 3)

Data in train_x:
[[ 1.18943379 -0.91710018  1.14258496]
 [-0.70887614  0.84737759 -0.2056342 ]
 [ 0.17527086  2.06309432 -1.33639865]
 
 [-0.70504165  0.69822715 -0.2056342 ]
 [-0.65522302 -0.0897374  -0.85799831]
 [ 2.56409815 -0.79609134  1.05560307]]
```

The code I am using:

```
def onehot_encoder(values):
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    integers = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)
    return integers


labels = onehot_encoder(labels)
labels = np.array(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)
datas = np.array(features)
# normalized = scaler.fit_transform(datas)

scaler2 = StandardScaler()
# fit scaler on data
scaler2.fit(datas)
# apply transform
standardized = scaler2.transform(datas)
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(standardized, labels, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)


print(train_x)

print(train_x.shape)
print(train_y.shape)

print(test_x.shape)
print(test_y.shape)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(30, activation='relu', input_shape=(30258, 3), return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(15, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
num_epochs = 500
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=1000)

score_train = model.evaluate(train_x, train_y)
print("Train accuracy: %", score_train[1] * 100)
```

Comment: As stated [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM): a `LSTM` layer expects *A 3D tensor with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`.* However, you have passes `train_x` with the shape (30258, 3). Your three features are ok, but you have specify timesteps and batches.

Comment: Hello, I have used: train_x = train_x[np.newaxis,:,:]
test_x = test_x[np.newaxis,:,:] to add new dimension to my data, now I getting the following error: ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1
  y sizes: 30258
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Comment: When I also rehsape the labels with:train_y = train_y[np.newaxis,:,:]
test_y = test_y[np.newaxis,:,:], the error changes to: ValueError: Shapes (None, 30258, 3) and (None, 3) are incompatible

Comment: Data Cardinality is due to ambiguity about your `X` and `y`. To resolve the issue, you should first clarify what does 30258 indicate? If you want to consider it as your timestep, then you have 1 sample, consequently, you should have 1 label (y shape=[1,3]). If you want to consider 30258 as batch size (add a new axis as the second dimension, instead of the first dimension), then you should have your label as it is now (y shape=[30258,1,3]).

Comment: 30258 indicates the amount of data in the training data but I was acting as if it was the timesteps your comment made me realize that. I have added new dimensions as:train_x = train_x[:,np.newaxis,:]
test_x = test_x[:,np.newaxis,:]
 and changed the input_shape to (1, 3), now the issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

30258 indicates the amount of data in the training data but I was acting as if it was the timesteps your comment made me realize that. I have added new dimensions as:

```
    train_x = train_x[:,np.newaxis,:] test_x = test_x[:,np.newaxis,:]
```

and changed the input_shape to (1, 3), now the issue is fixed